# Uploading a JSON file with Pyrebase to Firebase Storage from Google App Engine

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask, firebase-storage, pyrebase

I have a pretty simple Flask web app running in GAE that downloads a JSON file from Firebase Storage and replaces it with the updated one if necessary. Everything works ok but GAE throws an IOError exception whenever I try to create the a new file. I'm using Firebase Storage because I know it isn't possible to read/write files in a GAE environment but how I'm suppose to use Pyrebase `storage.child('foo.json').put('foo.json')` function then? What I'm doing wrong? Please, check my code below.

```
firebase_config = {my_firebase_config_dict}

pyrebase_app = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebase_config)
storage = pyrebase_app.storage()

@app.route('/')
def check_for_updates() :
    try :
        json_feeds = json.loads(requests.get('http://my-firebase-storage-url/example.json').text()
        # Here I check if I need to update example.json
        # ...
        with open("example.json", "w") as file:
            json.dump(info, file)
            file.close()
            storage.child('example.json').put('example.json')
        return 'finished successfully!'
    except IOError :
        return 'example.json doesn't exists'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just need this file temporary in GAE and put it in cloud storage afterwards. According to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-temp-files) you can do it as in normal OS, but in /tmp folder:

> if your app only needs to write temporary files, you can use standard
>   Python 3.7 methods to write files to a directory named /tmp

I hope it will help!

Comment: Didn't know that! Thank you! I finally used `blob.download_as_string()` and `blob.upload_from_string()` functions, so I don't have to save nothing into a file

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it like this but I don't know if this is better, worst or simply equivalent to @vitooh solution. Please, let me know:

```
firebase_config = {my_firebase_config_dict}

pyrebase_app = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebase_config)
storage = pyrebase_app.storage()

@app.route('/')
def check_for_updates() :
    try :
        blob = bucket.blob('example.json')
        example = json.loads(blob.download_as_string()
        # Here I check if I need to update example.json
        # ...
        if something_changed :
            blob.upload_from_string(example, content_type = 'application/json')
        return 'finished successfully!'
    except IOError :
        return 'example.json doesn't exists'
```